# Yocto: Is it possible to make use ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET} in Yocto Makefile?

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have botan.h available in ${STAGING_INCDIR}/botan-2. I like to use it in my yocto recipe along with my Makefile, my ideal is let "compilation" mentioned in Makefile rather than occupy the recipe entirely. Attched is my recipe and Makefile

recipe.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Makefile  Demo"
SECTION = "apps"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
DEPENDS = "botan"

APP_NAME = "integrated_app"
localdir = "/usr/local"
bindir = "${localdir}/bin"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp \
           file://Makefile \
       "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit pkgconfig 

do_compile() {
    # make -f Makefile
    oe_runmake
        
}

do_install () {
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${localdir}
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir}
    cd ${S}
    install -m 0755 ${APP_NAME} ${D}${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN}-dev = ""
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
```

Makefile

```
obj = main.o
target = integrated_app
S = "${WORKDIR}"
INC=/home/kjlau/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/botan-app/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/botan-2 

all: $(obj)
      ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $(obj)  -o $(target) 

%.o:%.cpp
     ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -I ${INC} -c $^  -o  $@  

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(obj) $(target)
```

Although it can successfully compile, but i wonder can we make use of ${STAGING_INCDIR}/botan-2 in Makefile? I tried , it not work though.I dont thing i implement the INC correctly, i mean it does not "common enough" such as i can't be assumed everyuser is kjlau right? Anyway to make it better?

Thanks

Comment: Is botan2.h installed using a different recipe? If so, can you just DEPENDS = "botan2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `TARGET_CXXFLAGS`. Add the following to your recipe:
`TARGET_CXXFLAGS += "-I ${STAGING_INC_DIR}/botan2"`. No need for `S=${WORKDIR}` and `INCDIR` in your Makefile.

Ideally, you'd add an install target in the Makefile and then your recipe would be as simple as:

```
SUMMARY = "Makefile  Demo"
SECTION = "apps"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
DEPENDS = "botan"

TARGET_CXXFLAGS += "-I ${STAGING_INC_DIR}/botan2"

SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp \
           file://Makefile \
       "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit pkgconfig
```

I'm not sure but I'd say that you also don't need to inherit pkgconfig.

Comment: I tried, it will prompt botan.h no such file or directory, from the debug log i saw  only "-I /botan2" , it seem like makefile cannot recognize  "recipe-sysroot/usr/include/botan-2"

Answer (score 0):

For oe_runmake, you can set
`EXTRA_OEMAKE += 'MY_SDK_PATH=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}'`
and use `MY_SDK_PATH` in your `Makefile` to reference the header, libs, etc.